# Crash on devices running iOS 8.4

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, crash-reports, ios8.4

Can anyone help here please?

I submitted version 2 of my app only to have it rejected as it crashed on a number of devices running 8.4 ….

```
{"bundleID":"properties.axxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx”,”app_name”:”My    App”,”share_with_app_devs":false,"name”:”My App”,”app_version":"2.0","is_first_party":false,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.4  (12H143)","bug_type":"109","slice_uuid":"c94c9011-955b-3d2c-b949- 5797aefef990","build_version":"2.2","adam_id":0}
Incident Identifier: A3B5332C-0A28-4E48-BFEE-F1FB95495715
CrashReporter Key:   09b24a3f5088bdc521191691c1969f4d0b4b4f7a
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,3
Process:             My App [1147]
Path:                 /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/6E6E3FFA-11CD-4DA0-995D-D46C8E2C9624/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          properties.axxxxxxx.xxxxxxxx
Version:             2.2 (2.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd.development [1]

Date/Time:           2015-09-20 01:23:11.929 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-09-20 01:23:11.557 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.4 (12H143)
UDID:                b01ae3fde269ba2ac345c6dae55c505ad34d45ae
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
2015-09-20 01:23:11.684 Alien Rabbits[1147]: <Error> assertion failed: 12H143: libxpc.dylib + 51915 [88A50DD0-8E7B-3CD6-AC30-BA113A415E4F]: 0x7d
2015-09-20 01:23:11.885 Alien Rabbits[1147]: <Error> +[NSMutableArray newMutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x31e2aaf4
2015-09-20 01:23:11.888 Alien Rabbits[1147]: <Error> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableArray newMutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x31e2aaf4'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x22a86fef 0x314a2c8b 0x22a8c325 0x22a8a327 0x229b9e78 0x610f5 0xb0507 0x91771 0x9116b 0xa3599 0x2b023 0x2616f243 0x26365ad9 0x26368199 0x26372e19 0x2636693b 0x2973eec9 0x22a4cfd5 0x22a4c299 0x22a4add3 0x22997201 0x22997013 0x26168e17 0x26163a09 0x2aecb 0x31a54aaf)

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x22a86fea 0x314a2c86 0x22a8c320 0x22a8a322 0x229b9e74 0x610f0 0xb0502 0x9176c 0x91166 0xa3594 0x2b01e 0x2616f23e 0x26365ad4 0x26368194 0x26372e14 0x26366936 0x2973eec4 0x22a4cfd0 0x22a4c294 0x22a4adce 0x229971fc 0x2299700e 0x26168e12 0x26163a04 0x2aec6 0x31a54aaa)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b1edf0 0x31b0a000 + 85488
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9dcc2 0x31b9a000 + 15554
```

2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31aba904 0x31a70000 + 305412
    3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30dc29c4 0x30dc2000 + 2500
    4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30ddc66c 0x30dc2000 + 108140
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x314a2f22 0x3149c000 + 28450
    6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30dd9de0 0x30dc2000 + 97760
    7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x30dd98aa 0x30dc2000 + 96426
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x314a2dce 0x3149c000 + 28110
    9   CoreFoundation                  0x22997298 0x2297f000 + 98968
    10  CoreFoundation                  0x2299700e 0x2297f000 + 98318
    11  UIKit                           0x26168e12 0x260f4000 + 478738
    12  UIKit                           0x26163a04 0x260f4000 + 457220
    13  My App                          0x0002aec6 0x23000 + 32454
    14  libdyld.dylib                   0x31a54aac 0x31a53000 + 6828

```
Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b0b224 0x31b0a000 + 4644
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a400ec 0x31a32000 + 57580
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a34d36 0x31a32000 + 11574

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: FBSSerialQueue
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b0b4c4 0x31b0a000 + 5316
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a3e5da 0x31a32000 + 50650
2   FrontBoardServices              0x2973eea6 0x29729000 + 89766
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a332e0 0x31a32000 + 4832
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a3b724 0x31a32000 + 38692
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a35aa8 0x31a32000 + 15016
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a3cf9c 0x31a32000 + 44956
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x31a3e3be 0x31a32000 + 50110
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9adbe 0x31b9a000 + 3518
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ab10 0x31b9a000 + 2832

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b1f9c0 0x31b0a000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ae38 0x31b9a000 + 3640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ab10 0x31b9a000 + 2832

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b1f9c0 0x31b0a000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ae38 0x31b9a000 + 3640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ab10 0x31b9a000 + 2832

 Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31b1f9c0 0x31b0a000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ae38 0x31b9a000 + 3640
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x31b9ab10 0x31b9a000 + 2832

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000003
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x344be9dc      r6: 0x344aa840      r7: 0x003233c8
    r8: 0x16e86fe0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x344a9074     r11: 0x16e87004
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x003233bc      lr: 0x31b9dcc7      pc: 0x31b1edf0
  cpsr: 0x00080010
```

No problems for me when running the app on an iPhone 6 with 8.4 and on a variety of devices running 8.0

The only way I have found to replicate the crash is running a device iPhone 4s on 8.0 using the profile tool and then I get:

```
2015-09-27 17:54:47.434 My App[9161:1516779] +[NSMutableArray newMutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x393e5960
2015-09-27 17:54:47.444 My APP[9161:1516779] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NSMutableArray newMutableArrayUsingWeakReferencesWithCapacity:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x393e5960'
```

*** First throw call stack:
    (0x2b20a5f7 0x38a7cc77 0x2b20f9d9 0x2b20d999 0x2b13eb88 0xc4501 0x11383b 0xf4a71 0xf4463 0x1068a9 0x8e523 0x2e719469 0x2e90e515 0x2e910a49 0x2e91b2f9 0x2e90f2eb 0x319800c9 0x2b1d0ffd 0x2b1d02c1 0x2b1cee1b 0x2b11bb31 0x2b11b943 0x2e713127 0x2e70df21 0x8e3cb 0x39018aaf)
    libc++abi.dylib:
    terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The app will run on that device if the profile tool is not used. When it is loaded with the profile tool it will crashes when phone is disconnected connected.

The app is crashing before its finished launching from:

```
-(BOOL) application: (UIApplication*) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: (NSDictionary*) launchOptions
```

and it’s the call to Initialise OpenAL:

```
  [OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance];
```

in the cocos2d CCAppDelegate.m file that triggers the crash.

If I take this call out, the crash happens a second or so later and the profile tool gives;

```
2015-09-27 18:38:52.634 My App[9188:1523335] -[EAGLContext ensureCurrentContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167918e0
2015-09-27 18:38:52.667 My App[9188:1523335] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EAGLContext ensureCurrentContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x167918e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2b20a5f7 0x38a7cc77 0x2b20fabd 0x2b20d999 0x2b13eb88 0x199c65 0x191f6d 0x19a063 0x19487f 0x10b4ad 0x10aa33 0x10a9fd 0x10aa75 0x1226f1 0x12341b 0x123225 0x1224e5 0x121b63 0x122a1d 0x7d5c9 0xf4ffd 0xa34b9 0xd799f 0x2e6ac19f 0x2e0d7f65 0x2e0d3951 0x2e0d37d9 0x2e0d31c7 0x2e0d2fd1 0x2e91011d 0x2e910eb5 0x2e91b2f9 0x2e90f2eb 0x319800c9 0x2b1d0ffd 0x2b1d02c1 0x2b1cea5f 0x2b11bb31 0x2b11b943 0x2e713127 0x2e70df21 0x7d3fb 0x39018aaf)
libc++abi.dylib:
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I’m using:

xcode 6.2

compiling to 8.0

cocos2d 3.2.1

Hours spent so far trying to resolve this.

Thanks